# How to evaluate python code provided by user?

Tags: python

Im experimenting with python programs that assist in learning python. Something like dynamic python test, for example program gives user a task of writing a function that will return sum of provided compounds. User input should be

```
def test(a,b):
    return a+b
```

how to evaluate user input? exec() prohibits returning anything from the code block, it is possible to define a function inside exec() and then evaluate it, but it is a security threat, because it allows user to redefine anything if global scope if passed.

What is the cleanest solution?

Comment: `eval()` does this, but *do not evaluate the user's code directly* Never let a (possibly malicious) user run their code on your system. Put it in some sort of sandbox so that it can't break the rest of your system if the user knows what they're doing. I don't know libraries that do this off the top of my head but they're absolutely out there.

Comment: i thought that eval allows only for statements, but not code. So a+b is ok, but defining a function is not allowed

Comment: I don't know about what `eval` allows (but there is [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) on that), but consider [`os.removedirs('/')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.removedirs)`is None` is a valid expression.